# How can I prove that the following function is increasing according to x1?

Tags: calculus-of-variations, gm.general-mathematics, derivations

Suppose that 
$0 \le {X_1} < {X_2} < {X_3}$
.
How is it possible to prove the following function is increasing based on 
${X_1}$
in the range of 
$0 \le {X_1} < {X_2}$ ?

$f({X_1},{X_2},{X_3}) = \frac{{(c + p{X_1}){{({X_2} - {X_3})}^2} + (c + p{X_2}){{({X_1} - {X_3})}^2} + (c + p{X_3}){{({X_1} - {X_2})}^2}}}{{{{[{X_1}{X_2}{\mkern 1mu} \log \frac{{{X_1}}}{{{X_2}}} + {X_1}{X_3}\log \frac{{{X_3}}}{{{X_1}}} + {X_2}{X_3}\log \frac{{{X_2}}}{{{X_3}}}]}^2}}}$

$c$ and $p$ are positive constants. 
I have plotted this function (as a function of ${X_1}$) and I observed that this is an increasing function. Then I tried to prove it analytically but taking derivative makes it too complicated, because I would come up with lots of conditions.

I also considered the numerator and denominator separately to investigate the behavior of each function, but it did not work. Because there was a contradiction in the common part of the conditions (ranges in which the derivative of numerator is positive and derivative of denominator is negative).

The most important point is that I **should not** put any constraint on ${X_1}$, but any condition is allowed to put on the ${X_2}$ and ${X_3}$.

Any kind of help would be so appreciated!

Comment: If $c$ and $p$ are fixed, it would help to give their values.  Or, if this is supposed to proved for all positive $c$ and $p$, then we can reduce to proving this in the case $c=0, \ p=1$ and the case $c=1,\ p=0$.

Comment: Thank you @MattF. , I did it but it does not help with the solution.

Comment: What did you do? What are $c$ and $p$?